# How can I batch convert FLAC to MP3 while retaining the directories, within a different directory?

Tags: windows, audio, conversion, mp3, music

I have my music organized as Music\Lossless\Artist\Album and Music\Lossy\Artist\Album. I want to convert everything in the lossless folder to MP3 or AAC, have them retain their Artist\Album directories, and be placed in "Music\Converted Lossy". I'd also like to retain all the tags/album art. And if it could check for what's already been converted that would be nice for future use.

What program is best for this? I usually use dBpoweramp but it doesn't have this feature as far as I can tell. Running Windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried fre:ac (http://www.freac.org/). You can set the output directory for the converted files ...

Comment: @DavidPostill It doesn't look like it can do what I need, thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dBpowermap music converter versions 10 and 11 (possibly later versions) have a utility in the program folder called "DMCFileSelector" which will batch convert and keep file paths. It is not on the all programs menu either.

[image]